# Java: How to prevent 'systemId' in EntityResolver#resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId) from being absolutized to current working directory

Tags: java, xml-parsing, entityresolver

I want to parse the following XML document to resolve all entities in it:

```
 <!DOCTYPE doc SYSTEM 'mydoc.dtd'>
 <doc>&title;</doc>
```

My EntityResolver is supposed to fetch the external entity with the given system ID from the database and then do the resolution, see below for an illustration:

```
 private static class MyEntityResolver
 {
    public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId)
        throws SAXException, IOException
    {
        // At this point, systemId is always absolutized to the current working directory, 
        // even though the XML document specified it as relative.
        // E.g. "file:///H:/mydoc.dtd" instead of just "mydoc.dtd"
        // Why???  How can I prevent this???

        SgmlEntity entity = findEntityFromDatabase(systemId);
        InputSource is = new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(entity.getContents()));
        is.setPublicId(publicId);
        is.setSystemId(systemId);
        return is;
    }
 }
```

I tried both using DOM (DocumentBuilder) and SAX (XMLReader), set the entity resolver to MyEntityResolver (i.e. `setEntityResolver(new MyEntityResolver())`), but `systemId` in `MyEntityResolver#resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId)` is always being absolutized to the current working directory.

I also tried calling `setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/resolve-dtd-uris", false);`, but that didn't help anything.

So how can I achieve what I wanted?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently, there is another interface called [EntityResolver2](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ext/EntityResolver2.html) which is the extension of the old [EntityResolver](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/EntityResolver.html).  (Talk about confusing names!)

Anyway, I found that `EntityResolver2` achieved what I wanted, that is, it does not make any changes to the `systemId`, so it will always exactly be what was specified in the XML document.

Answer (score 0):

From [the EntityResolver Javadocs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/org/xml/sax/EntityResolver.html):

> If the system identifier is a URL, the
>   SAX parser must resolve it fully
>   before reporting it to the
>   application.

Also, the [org.xml.sax docs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/package-summary.html) have this to say about the resolve-dtd-uris feature:

> It does not apply to
>   EntityResolver.resolveEntity(), which
>   is not used to report declarations...

I think you've either got to set your base-URI to something you can live with, or use public-IDs instead of system-IDs.