# saxreader validation fails when reading xml from java.io.Reader instead of providing path to xml file

Tags: java, xml, xml-validation

I have simple xml file contacts.xml located in subfolder *xml-files* of actual folder.

```
<contacts xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="contacts.xsd"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
    <contact> 
        <firstname>AAA</firstname> 
        <lastname>BBB</lastname>
    </contact> 
</contacts>
```

Schema file is also located in subfolder *xml-files*.

Code for parsing file:

```
  SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
  factory.setValidating(true);

  SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();                              
  parser.setProperty("http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaLanguage", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");

  SAXReader reader = new SAXReader(parser.getXMLReader());
  reader.setValidation(true);
  reader.read("xml-files/contacts.xml");
```

I want to use SAXReader's read method which takes java.io.Reader as parameter like this

```
reader.read(new FileReader("xml-files/contacts.xml"));
```

but I get exception

org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 2 of document  : cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'contacts'. Nested exception: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'contacts'.

Using custom entityresolver revealed that in the first case xsd files is being loaded from path file:///e:/devel/xsd/xml-files/contacts.xsd and in second case file:///e:/devel/xsd/contacts.xsd.

Is there any way to set to SAXReader the folder where xsd file should be located?

Comment: I haven't tried this, but take a look at this answer on another question and see if setting the schema on the SAXParserFactory works for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8282734/1423896

Comment: This works but I can't use it because there could are more xml files and they can have different xsd.

Comment: Check out the Javadoc for `SchemaFactory`(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/SchemaFactory.html#newSchema(javax.xml.transform.Source[])). The `newSchema(..)` method accepts an  array of `Source`. You might be able to throw all your schemas files into the `SchemaFactory` to get a consolidated `Schema` to set on your `SaxParserFactory`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by [Java: How to prevent 'systemId' in EntityResolver#resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId) from being absolutized to current working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648291/java-how-to-prevent-systemid-in-entityresolverresolveentitystring-publicid) I used my own implementation of EntityResolver2

```
private static class EntityResolver2Impl implements EntityResolver2 {
    private File xmlFile;
    public EntityResolver2Impl(File xmlFile) {
        this.xmlFile = xmlFile;
    }

    @Override
    public InputSource getExternalSubset(String name, String baseURI) throws SAXException, IOException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public InputSource resolveEntity(String name, String publicId, String baseURI, String systemId) throws SAXException, IOException {
        File entityPath = new File(xmlFile.getParent(), systemId);
        return new InputSource(new FileReader(entityPath));
    }

    @Override
    public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId) throws SAXException, IOException {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And the calling code looks like this

```
 File xmlFile = new File("xml-files/contacts.xml");
 SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();

 factory.setValidating(true);

 SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();                              
 parser.setProperty("http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaLanguage", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");

 SAXReader reader = new SAXReader(parser.getXMLReader());
 reader.setEntityResolver(new EntityResolver2Impl(xmlFile));
 reader.setValidation(true);
 reader.read(new FileReader(xmlFile));
```

This code can handle also cases where path to xsd contains relative paths leading to parent folders (../..) etc.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but from my comments above this is what I'm thinking:

```
    SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setValidating(true);

    SchemaFactory schemafactory =   SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

    Source[] sources = new Source[] {
        new StreamSource(new File("path/to/schema1.xsd")),
        new StreamSource(new File("path/to/schema2.xsd")),
        new StreamSource(new File("path/to/schema3.xsd")),
        new StreamSource(new File("path/to/schema4.xsd")),
    };

    Schema sc = schemafactory.newSchema(sources);
    factory.setSchema(sc);

    SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
    parser.parse(file, handler);
```